Defining Integral operator and proof of laws
I would like to make a definition of the Integral operator and proofs of laws about the integral operator.  How can I go about it?
Have started like this in Temporal Logic of Actions (TLA)
EXTENDS Naturals, RealNumbers, Sequences

VARIABLES x, t, f

(* Abstract function definition: f(t) maps time t to a real number *)
Function(t) == [t ∈ RealNumbers |-> f(t)]

(* Riemann Sum Definition *)
Partition(a, b, n) == <<i ∈ 0..n-1 :-> a + i * ((b - a) / n)>>

RiemannSum(a, b, n) == LET dx == (b - a) / n
                         IN Sum(0, n-1, LAMBDA i: f(a + i * dx) * dx)

(* Limit definition of definite integral *)
Integral(a, b) == LIM(n ∈ Naturals, RiemannSum(a, b, n))


I would strongly recommend not making your own integral operator. I don’t know how much you know about integration, but the theory behind it is actually fairly complicated. You might be able to rush Riemann integration (as taught in calculus), but then you will have some trouble with certain uses of integration. Or if you only care about continuous functions on the interval, then you can use Riesz representation, but again you will struggle to generalize it. I think Lean, Isabelle, and Coq all have fairly fleshed out libraries with integration.

What spaces do you want to integrate over (closed intervals, real line, complex numbers, probability/measure spaces)?  What types of functions do you want to integrate (continuous, a.e. continuous, L1/measurable, random variables)?  What properties do you have in mind to prove (linearity, calculus identities, complex integration, change of bases, measure theory facts, probability facts)?

So I can define the fourier transform.  I do not need a too general scheme, but to understand a little how things would look like defining some basic definitions.  Is the one in Coq very complicated ?

Your question is missing a lot of context: do you have a particular proof assistant in mind? A particular library? Why do you want to define integration/the Fourier transform: is this an exercise for yourself? Do you have another goal in mind?

Have opted for Coq but I am exploring its potential for structuring and organizing mathematical correctness proofs, leveraging the hierarchically structured proof methodology introduced by Leslie Lamport.  Not really for checking proofs with a computer but for writing proof on paper where it would simplify writing the code to test it.

Yes, it is an exercise for me.

In general, setting up definitions "right" is a very subtle thing in proof assistants. I would advise you to explore an existing library and benefit from the set up already in place rather than building from scratch. In Coq, the best place would likely be https://github.com/math-comp/analysis.
